# how to use a variable in head function in for loop in unix shell

Tags: shell, unix

i'm very new, and am working on variables.

i wonder how can I use a variable in head function

for example,

```
for ((i=0; i<5; i++))
head -((1+i)) test.txt
```

but it displays an error. how can i fix this?

Comment: Are you wanting to show a certain number of lines using `head`?

Comment: Yes exactly,I got my answer from the comments down here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
for ((i=1; i<6; i++))
do
    head -n$i test.txt
done
```

Notice that I've started the variable `i` at `1` so that we don't get an error from `head` *(like: `head: illegal line count -- 0`)*.  And you can access the `i` variable by using `$i` in your loop.